# Display Bootstrap modal on if all required fields are completed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Here's my current design:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 well">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input id="fn" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input id="ln" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
                data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#signup">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="signup" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Signing up. Please wait...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The design allows me to display a static modal after pressing the submit button. This prevent any user to modify anything during the signup process.

However, the modal skips the validation for required fields:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to trigger the validation first before displaying the modal?

Comment: Are you using jqvaldiation plugin or custom scripts to validate?

Comment: @kiranvj I'm only using HTML required attribute but I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: HTML-based validation using the `required` attribute will not block JS events arising from form submission. You will probably need a library to perform that validation so that you can decide if the form is valid upon submit, and then decide if the modal should be shown.

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311923/javascript-validation-for-all-field-with-required-attribute

Answer (score 2):

First you need to trigger the modal manually. Remove all data attributes from button and change button type to button

```
<button id="submit-button" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit
            </button>
```

Next you need to handle button click and check the input fields.

```
$(function() {
   $("#submit-button").click(function() {
       if($("#fn").val() !="" && $("#ln").val() !="") {
         $('#signup').modal('show');
         $(this).closest("form").submit(); 
       }
   });
});
```

NB: there might be better approaches

[Related info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707743/html5-validation-when-the-input-type-is-not-submit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `required` attribute. Launch modal after checking their content and if its empty (for example) close modal and show error:

```
$('#signup').modal('hide');
```